Is it possible to have a child model with multiple parents in a Django App?
I am creating a quiz back-end. I would like to add a feature where a user can report a question for being irrelevant or not fair.
I have 3 relevant models for this in my Django app:

User Model
Question Model
Report Model

I would like to record what user created the report and also what question was reported.
Is it possible to have a Many to 1 relationship between Report:User and also a Many to 1 relationship between Report:Question too?
The report model would have two parents - User and Question.
Is there a better way of doing this?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

just add foreign field
class user:
  ...
class quiz:
  ...
class report:
  reporter = models.ForeignKey(user)
  quiz = models.ForeignKey(quiz)
  ...

